# Problems creating a bullet and number list with markdown

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, markdown

I'm struggling to format a bullet list, a number list and then a bullet list.

This question isn't looking right:
[Frequent error messages when connecting to Windows file shares from a Mac under a VPN connection](https://serverfault.com/questions/64230/frequent-error-messages-when-connecting-to-windows-file-shares-from-a-mac-under-a)

Is there a bug in markdown or did I screw something up?

Let me specify:
I'm trying to create a 2 item bullet list, some space, then a 3 item number list, some space, a then 2 item bullet list.

Here is my source:

```
- "The operation cannot be completed because one or more required items cannot be found. (Error code -1401)"
- "The Finder cannot complete the operation because some data in "home1-final.psd" could not be written. (Error code -36)"

1. This user has been accessing files this way without problems for over a year
2. No configuration changes or installations have occurred on the file server of the client/user Mac since the problem began
3. The user can use the files most of the time, but frequently gets these errors.

- Windows Server 2003
- Mac OS X 10.50.8
```

But if you look at the link above, it doesn't render that way.

Comment: Now that it's working, i just gotta say: you'd probably be better off making the middle list a normal paragraph. As it stands, your question is rather... *list-heavy*!

Comment: Not sure why "bug" was removed. I know Coding Horror doesn't believe in bugs, is that why?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

They're being merged because they have the same indentation and nothing but whitespace in between. You *could* do [like Jonathan did](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/21233/problems-creating-a-bullet-and-number-list-with-markdown/21234#21234), and just change the indentation from list-to-list, but this might not work if you don't intend one list to be a subset of an item in the preceding list. Easiest solution? [Just throw a `&nbsp;` in between 'em](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/revisions/f61b7a81-17b4-4305-9096-48af6b1cc545/view-source):

1. One
2. Two

- Three
- Four

If the excess whitespace annoys you, then [consider using a horizontal rule](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/21233/problems-creating-a-bullet-and-number-list-with-markdown/21234#21234):

1. One
2. Two

---

- Three
- Four

If *none* of that works for you, then you're left with the option of [using straight HTML](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/revisions/0ff2f237-729e-4758-b793-d14bbe3e3d8e/view-source):

- One
- Two

1. One
2. Two

- Note that ordinary Markdown syntax [*doesn't* work within block-level HTML](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/editing-help)

Comment: I mean, I know it's likely I'm screwing something up, but I have line breaks between them. Even ODDMuse can handle this.

Comment: @Justin: line breaks count as whitespace. Whitespace *doesn't* count as a list terminator. That's just how Markdown works. You need *something* else between the lists.

Comment: Huh, OK. Odd that it hasn't been replaced. I'll fix it.

Comment: @Shog9 - Thanks, fixed.

Answer (score 15):

Like this? Note, when doing nested lists, the preview window is a super big help. Inserted how ever many spaces it takes to pop that list into existence.

- No problems exist
- You made it all up

  1. You probably missing something big

     - That isn't really important though
     - I don't mean to pry
  2. You might have just not indented enough times

     - That seems more likely
- This helps, right?

Source:

```
- No problems exist
- You made it all up
 1. You probably missing something big
     - That isn't really important though
     - I don't mean to pry
 2. You might have just not indented enough times
     - That seems more likely
- This helps, right?
```

Comment: I find it works best if the indention is in multiples of four.

Answer (score 0):

I think in this specific case what you're doing doesn't lead to a particularly readable post, so I'm inclined to call this "it hurts when I do that, so don't do that."

Beyond that, use `&nbsp;` if you need an artificial paragraph break between sections.