# Numbered list misaligned when I use intermediate bullet points

Tags: support, list

When creating [this answer](https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/21881/sony-movie-studio-platinum-13-rendering-output-movie-freezes-or-has-glitches/21882#21882), I cannot make points 3 and 4 (in the red rectangle) line up with numbered points 1 and 2. I have followed the "Styling/Headers" suggestions with spaces in multiples of 4.

[image]

I don't really want to add `&nbsp;` as mentioned [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/21233/problems-creating-a-bullet-and-number-list-with-markdown/21234#21234), because it adds a very large amount of whitespace, and makes the answer look odd.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. I can
2. Make

   - Such
   - Type
3. Of
4. Lists

### For that

## Add an extra line after the `-` bulletin before continuing the number bulletin

### And

## Align the numbered bulletins without any padding in the left.

#### You added 2 spaces before the numbered bulletin(I mean 1 and 2)

```
1. I can
2. Make 
  - Such
  - Type

3. Of
4. Lists
```

---

<sup>I made an edit suggestion to your answer to correct it.</sup>

Comment: Thanks for the edit. I looked at the first draft and understand what you mean about the spaces I had before the first numbered bullet. I have upvoted your response, but I currently don't have enough Meta reputation for my vote to show.

Comment: @MechtEngineer Glad it helped mate. you can accept it.

Comment: Please be patient! There is a time [delay](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/50697/time-limit-on-accepting-an-answer) before I can accept an answer.

Comment: Sorry actually I didn't noticed the time. hmm a space is there between `[]` and `()` which break the link.

Comment: Adding spaces seems to be my recurring problem! :) Fixed it. Thanks.